# Javascript addEventListener no funciona en un lugar de mi codigo pero en otro si

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tratare de explicar mi problema.

Tengo dos botones, uno para borrar el registro y otro para editar el registro,
puse ambos dentro de una forma (form).

Cuando el usuario pulse en cualquiera de ellos debera de ejecutar su respectiva funcion.

```js
const formEditDel = document.querySelector('form#ed');
        const userDel = formEditDel.querySelector('input#buttonDelete');
        const userEdit = formEditDel.querySelector('input#buttonEdit');

        eventListeners();

        function eventListeners() {
            userDel.addEventListener('submit', markDeleted);
            userEdit.addEventListener('submit', userEdited);
        }

        function markDeleted(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            console.log('^*^*^ markDeleted *^*^*');

        }

        function userEdited(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            console.log('^*^*^ userEdited *^*^*');
        
        }
```

```html
    <form id="ed" method="POST">
       <input type="hidden" id="tipoAccion" name="tipoAccion" value="delete">
       <input type="submit" id="buttonDelete" value="BORRAR">
    
       <input type="hidden" id="tipoAccion" name="tipoAccion" value="edit">
       <input type="submit" id="buttonEdit" value="EDITAR">
    </form>
```

Mi problema es que los addEventListener no estan funcionando y por lo tanto no entran
a ejecutar la funcion que les corresponden.

Como podran ver en la imagen de abajo la consola muestra que los querySelectors son correctos
sin embargo los eventListener no estan funcionando

[image: imagen de lo que muestra la consola del navegador]

Ojala alguien pueda ayudarme a entender que es lo que esta pasando.

De antemano gracias por cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los botones deben tener el evento `click`.

```
function eventListeners() {
      userDel.addEventListener('click', markDeleted);
      userEdit.addEventListener('click', userEdited);
}
```

Comment: Mil gracias por la respuesta, ya esta funcionando.